# Prestashop subcategory parent

Tags: prestashop, categories

I have a little question with prestashop. When a user is on one of the subcategory of the category A, display the information (description, title and picture) of the category A and not the informations of the subcategory where the user is.

With the smarty `{$category.id_parent}` i can display the ID of the parent category but for example, i want to use `{$category.description_parent}`

Do you have a tips ? 
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Use a Module, you cannot inject PHP inside Smarty in Prestashop. You need prior work :

1 - Create a module with a custom hook (like displayMySuperHook).

2 - Implement your hook in the template :

```
  {hook h='displayMySuperHook' current_category=$category}
```

3 - In your PHP do something like this :

```
public function hookDisplayMySuperHook($params) {
   if (isset($params['current_category']) && Validate::isLoadedObject($params['current_category'] && !empty($params['current_category']->id_parent)) {
       $parent_category = new Category((int) $params['current_category']->id_parent);
       // Maybe check Validate::isLoadedObject on parent category here
       $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
           "parent_category" => $parent_category,
       ));

       return $this->display(__FILE__, 'templatename.tpl');
   }
}
```

4 - Create a template with what you need in your module (/moduledir/views/templates/hook/templatename.tpl).