# Prestashop: Get parent category informations from the sub-category page

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I build a site on prestashop with a child theme based on the classic theme.
For my needs i've got a page for main categories with an hero section where i display the main category name, the cover image of the category, the sub-categories and a description. (see on the attached image)

[hero section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQyqm.jpg)

Now i need to keep this section like that when i go to the sub-category page. Keep the title, image, sub-categories, etc. Just the content must change.

For now there is my code to display this hero section, located in the layout-left-column.tpl (to be before all the main content and after the header) :

```
{block name="hero_content"}
    {if Tools::getValue('id_category') == 11 || 19 || 20 || 21 || 22 || 23}
        <div class="category_hero" style="background-image: url('{$urls.img_url}categories/volailles_image_cover.jpg')">
            {if $listing.pagination.items_shown_from == 1}
                <div class="category_hero_title">
                    <h1 class="h1">{$category.name}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="category_hero_subcategories">
                    {include file='catalog/_partials/subcategories.tpl'}
                </div>
                <div class="category_hero_description">
                    {$category.description nofilter}
                </div>
            {/if}
        </div>
    {/if}
{/block}
```

But as i expected when i go to a sub-category this section change with the informations of this sub-category.

How can i keep this section with the parent category informations ?

Ps: I tried to hit the function Category::getParentsCategories(), but nothing. And i'm working with Prestashop 1.7.8.3

Thank's for your time.

Comment: Please do not add "(Solved)" to the title. The system automatically marks the post when an answer is accepted (the Green checkmark next to an answer)

Comment: ok ! i know it now, thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE] Problem Solved

I finaly solved my problème with this topic :
[Prestashop subcategory parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325850/prestashop-subcategory-parent)

And with adaptations :

In a custom module class where i create a function :

```
public function hookDisplayHeaderCategory($params) {
        if (isset($params['current_category']) && !empty($params['current_category'])) {
            $id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
            $parent_category = new Category((int) $params['current_category']);
            $sub_categories = Category::getChildren((int) $params['current_category'], $id_lang);
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($parent_category)) {
                $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                    "parent_category" => $parent_category,
                    "parent_category_name"   =>  $parent_category->name,
                    "parent_category_description"   => $parent_category->description,
                    "sub_categories"    =>  $sub_categories,
                ));
            }
        }

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'category_hero.tpl');
    }
```

Create a view in this module with the hero section :

```
<div class="category_hero" style="background-image: url('{$urls.img_url}categories/volailles_image_cover.jpg')">
        <div class="category_hero_title">
            <h1 class="h1">{$parent_category_name[1]}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="category_hero_subcategories">
            {include file='catalog/_partials/subcategories.tpl' subcategories=$sub_categories}
        </div>
        <div class="category_hero_description">
            {$parent_category_description[1] nofilter}
        </div>
</div>
```

If it can help somebody in the same case.